# Generate exact same PDF from HTML in both client and server side

Tags: angular, pdf, .net-core

Can we generate exact same PDF from HTML by using the same library or any other way(formatting of the PDF  should be same) in angular 6 and .net core?
I want to provide preview first and if the user will confirm then it will call the API.
Any lead will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to send the same html rendered to screen to a headless browser, using puppeteer/chromium which can create PDF from html.

We have done this for reporting that replicates some UI elemenets.

re: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

We also use a remote browser: https://www.browserless.io